# C++ Understanding Complex Function Signature

Tags: c++

While reading some code, I came across this function. I have lots of trouble understanding the signature of the function. What are the things that I need to know before I can make head or tail of the following code?
I have been using C++ for a while now. I know what templates, function pointers are. However, I cannot make out what `T::*` might mean, what the line starting with `_Defer` means semantically.
Also, the first line of the function seems quite intimidating. Is there some resource that I can read up before trying to re-assess this code?

```
template <typename T>
_Defer<void(*(PID<T>, void (T::*)(void)))
       (const PID<T>&, void (T::*)(void))>
defer(const PID<T>& pid, void (T::*method)(void))
{
  void (*dispatch)(const PID<T>&, void (T::*)(void)) =
    &process::template dispatch<T>;
  return std::tr1::bind(dispatch, pid, method);
}
```

Source: https://github.com/3rdparty/libprocess/blob/master/include/process/defer.hpp

Comment: Try splitting it up into smaller parts. Start with the template argument, the return type, the function name and arguments, and the function body. Then split each part up further, like the the return type (which is a `_Defer` templated class), the arguments to the function, etc. In other words, try to understand it top to bottom, try to understand the larger parts before the smaller parts (like member function pointers etc.).

Comment: Since the return type starts with underscore-capital, you can assume that you don't need to know the details of the return type. Then again, the return type isn't part of the function signature, so perhaps you weren't asking about that anyway...

Comment: `void (T::*)(void)` is an annoying way of spelling `void (T::*)()`. The latter is a pointer to a class member of a class `T` of type `void()`; in other words, `method` is a pointer to a member function of `T`.

Comment: The 2nd argument is a member function pointer.  That isn't enough to make a call to the function, you also need a reference to the object.  That's the 1st argument.  If you ever have written any .NET code then you'll understand the concept of a *delegate*, this is it.

Answer (score 5):

This might help clear things up a little:

```
template<typename T>
using VoidPMemberFn = void(T::*)(); // Pointer to member function of T
                                    // that accepts no arguments and
                                    // returns nothing.

template<typename T>
using DeferResultType = void (*)(const PID<T> &, VoidPMemberFn<T>);

template<typename T>
using DeferSignatureType = DeferResultType<T>(PID<T>, VoidPMemberFn<T>);

template<typename T>
_Defer<DeferSignatureType<T>> defer(const PID<T> &pid, VoidPMemberFn<T> method)
{
    // Stuff...
}
```

**EDIT**

This might help clarify what the spaghetti in the `_Defer` template means, and how it relates to the above:

```
void(* (PID<T>, void (T::*)(void)) )(const PID<T>&, void (T::*)(void))
^-+^-^ ^-------------------------^  ^-------------+------------------^
  |           argument list                       |
  |                                               |
  +-----------------------------------------------+
              return type:  void(*)(const PID<T> &, void(T::*)(void))
```

This creates a "signature", like those used with `std::function` (e.g. `std::function<int(float)>`).

More examples:

```
using sig = int(float);

sig gn; // Same as: "int gn(float)", a function declaration

int fn(float x)
{return (int)x;}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // pointer to a function with signature "sig"
    sig *pfn = &fn;
    return 0;
}

int gn(float x)
{return (int)(x*x);}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is non-standard non-portable code and hence hard to decode for humans. The return type

```
_Defer<void(*(PID<T>, void (T::*)(void)))(const PID<T>&, void (T::*)(void))>
```

is a specialisation of some class template `_Defer` defined in some header included. It is explained in defube's answer.

However, `_Defer<>` is not part of the `std` library specification and hence using it in this way makes the code non-portable and hence non-standard compliant. The same holds for the usage of `std::tr1::bind` instead of `std::bind`.

I guess your function's C++14 equivalent is simply

```
template <typename T>
auto defer(const PID<T>& pid, void (T::*method)())
{
  auto dispatch = &process::template dispatch<T>;
  return std::bind(dispatch, pid, method);
}
```

where `process` must be some class (or base class if `defer` is a member function) with static template member method `dispatch`. Thus, `defer()` returns some function object (see the [documentation for `std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)) to be called later.

Note that the return type of `std::bind` is *unspecified* by the standard and hence `auto` (or packaging it into a `std::function`) the only portable way to handle it.

Comment: Who's to say `_Defer<T>` doesn't have a constructor that looks like `template<typename AnyType, SFINAE constraints...> _Defer(AnyType &&any)` ?